# Get a cell relative to another from a named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using MS Excel 2007. I use a named range `SysData`.

```
=MAX(SysData)
```

returns the max value.

How can I return the value in the cell to the right and left of this maximum?

I tried getting the reference for the cell containing the max value as a starting point using:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(SysData,MATCH(MAX(SysData),SysData,0)))
```

but this returns N/A.

Here is a sample of my spreadsheet:

[spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFyqE.png)

`SysData` is B3:B5, B6 has the formula max(SysData)

As you can see - it didnt work
I also tried the alternative formula

`=ADDRESS(ROW(SysData)+INDEX(SysData,MAX(SysData))-1,COLUMN(SysData))`

which also gives `#REF!`

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
INDEX(sysdata,,MATCH(MAX(sysdata),sysdata,FALSE)-1)
```

the match returns the column number and the 1 is added or removed to get the value of the cell either side.

In response to the comment it does not work, the image shows the sheet and the range of sys data is D2:L2.

[image]

Comment: Tried - but it also returns #N/A. I read something about having to use N() or T() function to force numeric or text results as this was a known problem - but I cant find the reference now

Comment: I don't see why - tested this on a sheet and it works.

Comment: I just copied your formula and added an '=' at the beginning

Comment: Ok so named range is case sensitive

Comment: case sensitive and no spaces allowed... I've been caught like that :)

Comment: So now it nearly works - but '-1' gives cell above not left or right - data is in columsn.

Comment: And the ',,' didnt help

Comment: are you sure you have the formula correct - with the index function, there are two commas after sysdata before the match starts. If you only have 1 comma then it works on rows...

Comment: =INDEX(SysData,,MATCH(MAX(SysData),SysData,FALSE)-1) gives #REF

Comment: =INDEX(SysData,MATCH(MAX(SysData),SysData,FALSE)-1) returns cell above

Comment: the arguments to index() are, in order, array, row,column so the commas in mine were placed to make sure that the column was used not the row.

Answer (score 0):

If you data is in a column you can use this:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(SysData)+INDEX(SysData,MAX(SysData))-1,COLUMN(SysData))
```

And, if your data is an a row you can use this:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(SysData),COLUMN(SysData)+INDEX(SysData,MAX(SysData))-1)
```

Once you have the cell you can then use `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` to get a cell relative to the one that contains the `MAX`. E.g. where the data is in a row:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(SysData),COLUMN(SysData)+INDEX(SysData,MAX(SysData))-1)),0,-1)
```

[image]

### Edit

If you data is in a single 2d range the formula is a bit different:

To identify the cell of the maximum number:

```
=ADDRESS(
  SUMPRODUCT(--(SysData=MAX(SysData))*ROW(SysData)),
  SUMPRODUCT(--(SysData=MAX(SysData))*COLUMN(SysData))
)
```

And then, to get some offset, you can just do the same process with `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET`:

```
=OFFSET(
  INDIRECT(
    ADDRESS(
      SUMPRODUCT(--(SysData=MAX(SysData))*ROW(SysData)),
      SUMPRODUCT(--(SysData=MAX(SysData))*COLUMN(SysData))
    )
  ),
 0,-1)
```

The two `SUMPRODUCT` formulas are basically looking at the array of the data e.g.

`{1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9; 0,10,0}`

And saying converting it to an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` based on whether there is a match to the `MAX` e.g.:

`{FALSE,FALSE,FALSE; FALSE,FALSE,FALSE; FALSE,FALSE,FALSE; FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}`

Then the double unary operator converts to `0` and `1` e.g.

`{0,0,0; 0,0,0; 0,0,0; 0,1,0}`

Because `ROW(SysData)` or `COLUMN(SysData)` are themselves arrays of the absolute row and column references of the named range then multiplying those arrays by the 0/1 array returns the location of the `MAX` value.

In my example below the `SysData` array is `B2:D5` and the ROW array is:

`{2,3,4,5}`

And the column array is:

`{2,3,4}`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So, we both have working solutions except for the OP - why?

Comment: More the merrier ? :)

Comment: The mechanics of yours and mine work - would it be something to do with the range - are there any error values in the original range which obviously don't exist in ours?

Comment: If there's error values or the range is 2d my method won't work.

Comment: Ahh, mine does not work either on those 2d or errors, perhaps that's it

Comment: no - its 1d - but see updatated question with sample spreadsheet

Comment: The sample I have shown is 1d - 3 cells vertical. But my application has a discontinuolus range Data!$B$24:$B$65,Data!$E$24:$E$65,Data!$H$24:$H$65

Comment: If you have a vertical range, then what I did for you won't work - I had assumed that when you said "the value to the left and right of the maximum" that you were working with columns. You will need to edit the index function and move the match function into the row position. I also tested and it does not work with a range that is not 1d as per the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking - the #REF comes from the index() bit.

Comment: Just made the range in my example 2d and the match function throws the first error. Big question : can you make your data contiguous? if so, then it can be made to work...

Comment: Thanks Both - whilst I wasnt able to make the data contiguous I did find a way to make it work using this last solution, The raw data is 3 pieces of control process data per day every week. It is the central data value that needs to be used to find MAX and then the left and right side data returned. I actually have 21 cols (7 days @3 per day and the weeks grow, well, weekly.

Comment: iT wasnt an elegant solution - essentially I had to make a copy of the centre points as a contiguous array. off to the right of the original. Then once I had the row I could look up in the row and find the original value and then return the side data